# Allowing multiple phone numbers in a database?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This is my first time posting here, so please bear with me if I am doing something wrong. I am hung up on one portion a homework assignment and was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction, or at least let me know if my idea on what I need to do is correct. I am using mySQL and I am a beginner in databases.

The question reads "The database needs to support multiple (any quantity of) phone numbers per customer.  Currently only one number is allowed (Customer.Phone).  Each phone number also needs a type, which must be: land line (L), mobile (M), or work (W).  No additional types are expected.  The current 50-character limit is sufficient.  Assume all current phone numbers in the table are type=L."

I was going to:

create a new table CUSTOMERPHONE with the columns customerNumber(FK, it is the primary in CUSTOMER), phoneType(together with customerNumber, these 2 would be the primary key), and phone. 
The CUSTOMER and CUSTOMERPHONE tables would have a 1:M relationship- 1 customer can have many phone numbers.

In the CUSTOMER table, I was going to add a column phoneType. customer.phoneType would become a foreign key linking the two tables.

I have not written any code for this portion of the assignment yet, with my luck I would  somehow break my database and mess up the other 3 portions of the assignment. If someone could tell me if my line of thinking is correct, or where it is flawed, I'd appreciate it. (I don't expect a solution being that is it homework, just some feedback.)

Comment: If you're worried about breaking things, take a backup before doing anything. But yes, your general approach sounds like you're going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your line of thinking is right on. You do not need to add the phoneType column to the customer because that relationship is already defined in the CUSTOMERPHONE table as you described.

Also remember that this really isn't a one-to-many relationship, it's more of a one-to-3 relationship because it will depend on how many different types you allow.

Answer (score 0):

Your thinkngis good, but don't bother with this one piece:
`In the CUSTOMER table, I was going to add a column phoneType. customer.phoneType would become a foreign key linking the two tables.`
It would just clutter the design.